# How to get selected item of combobox bound to Collection View Source

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, combobox, collectionviewsource

Can't seem to find a solution to this. I have a view model with 2 observable collections and a view with a single combobox that is bound to those 2 observable collections through a collection view source.

Here is the XAML:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding selectedvalue}">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CustomCollection1" Source="{Binding Collection1}"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CustomCollection2" Source="{Binding Collection2}"/>
    </ComboBox.Resources>

    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomCollection1}}"/>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomCollection2}}"/>
       </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>

    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
               <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Balance, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
               </Grid>
           </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Seemingly no matter what I do I can not get the selected value. I have other comboboxes working just fine so I know that in most cases the Selectedvalue and SelectedValuePath give the desired result. But it doesn't seem to work for collection view source all I get is the path to the property rather than the value itself.

So how do I get the selected value from a combobox bound to a collection view source using mvvm?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Didn't know you could do that.  Why not just `Aggregate` the two `ObservableCollection`s into one?  Would perhaps make your XAML easier?

Comment: And I didn't know you could do that. Something to keep in mind for the future. I ended up fixing my issue though. Turns out that selected value with selected value path does work on composite collection. I'm not sure what was preventing it from working before but it is working now. Thank you for you help!